# Using NM on Mac apps --malformed object

Tags: macos, debugging, nm

I've just started working with some debugging utilities including nm. I want to analyze some programs on my computer.  A few that I have downloaded like Sublime Text work just fine using both:

```
nm Sublime\ Text\ 2
nm -arch x86_64 Sublime\ Text\ 2
```

However other apps I try and analyze throw errors like the following:

```
nm: object: ForkLift malformed object (unknown load command 34)
```

I'm sure there is an obvious reason why it does this, but I'm completely drawing a blank.

Comment: Which `nm` are you using? It works fine for me on ForkLift, for example.

Comment: Is there a quick way to check that?  Using --version doesn't work with nm.

Comment: `which nm` should be fine; OS X/Xcode versions would be helpful too.

Comment: which nm just gives me the path /usr/bin/nm   -  I don't have xcode (trying to get by without having to download it) OSX 10.8.4

Comment: Not sure why you're trying to avoid it (unless you're on a really slow/expensive Internet connection?) — but it would include a newer version of `nm` than the one bundled with the OS.  You could try downloading the command-line tools only from developer.apple.com.  I haven't had trouble with `nm` from Xcode 4.6.3 on any App Store apps — I don't believe they are encrypted.

Comment: Just because I don't utilize much of it.  I compiled all programs I've needed outside of xcode so far.  I did however download and install it to see if that was the issue and it didn't fix the issue, so I'm going to assume that the answer below is the real issue, not the version.

Answer (score 1):

One of the things that can cause nm to choke is the DRM on Mac App Store and App Store purchases.  If your copy of ForkLift happened to come from a source employing DRM this can cause diagnostic tools like nm to fail to function or to return results that are incomplete, inconsistent, or otherwise incorrect.  It seems as though you are learning about the capabilities of these tools, how they work, and when are the right kinds of situations to use such tools — GREAT!  Start with smaller, simple apps that aren't wrapped by a DRM protection layer and work your way up to more complex pieces of software.  It is amazing what you can learn about an app!

These tools can be used on DRM protected binaries, however I must respectfully decline to discuss more on that particular facet of this natural follow up question.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I assume this is the issue I am running into since a number of smaller programs downloaded and compiled outside of the app store seem to work just fine.  The issue of stripping the DRM from software is something that is covered a number of different ways by a number of different people.  If anyone has a link that sums up the best how to that would be great, but considering the nature, it's not surprising if no one is willing.